# Display JDialog below caret position

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jdialog

I would like to display `JDialog` below the current caret position in `JTextArea` in my program. I tried using, `modelToView()` to get the caret position but when i use the `setLocation()` method of the `JDialog` in this way, I am unable to get the desired location.

```
Rectangle r=jTextArea.modelToView(jTextArea.getCaretPosition());
jDialog.setLocation(r.x,r.y+jTextArea.getFontMetrics(jTextArea.getFont()).getHeight());
```

Also, could any one tell me why this snippet is not working in the desired way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rectangle is likely relative to the parent component.  You need to translate the location to the screen

```
SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(r.getLocation(), jTextArea);
jDialog.setLocation(pos.x,pos.y+jTextArea.getFontMetrics(jTextArea.getFont()).getHeight());
```

I've not tried this, but I think...

```
jDialog.setLocation(pos.x,pos.y+r.height);
```

Might be cleaner...?

Comment: convertPointToScreen() return type is void